# Why don't the authors use the articles 'a' and 'an' infront of the the words 'period' and 'entity' respectively?

Tags: articles, definite-article, indefinite-article

This is an excerpt from The IBM Style Guide for technical writers:

> *In books, use a period in titles for chapters and appendixes. Insert the period after the name of the entity and the identifying number or letter and before the descriptive name.*
>
> ```
> Examples
> Chapter 1. Introduction to InfoBase
> Appendix A. Performance considerations
> Appendix B. Conversion tables
> ```

Why don't the authors write it as follows?

> *In books, use a period in titles for chapters and appendixes. Insert **a** period after the name of **an** entity and the identifying number or letter and before the descriptive name.*

Comment: I believe that is because "period" is only, well, a period. There are not many things like the period or the full-stop. It is unique. There are not types as such.

Comment: @DhanishthaGhosh But they use "a period" in the first sentence.

Comment: But that's the point. They have told you to use a period. Where do you use that period? After the name of the entity.

Comment: I agree with Daniel. On the other hand, I would like to add that 'an' instead of 'the' in the second sentence would work just fine. Like the entity can be any entity in general, and the descriptive name can be a descriptive name or title for anything in general.

Comment: OK, guys, thanks. It seems now I understand.